# Codeigniter Bootstrap Modal Delete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

So I wanted to delete a row in a table using a delete button, which will then show a modal to confirm the delete process. However, I need to pass the ID, in this case I used filename, to the URL in order to complete the delete process. However, I can't seem to pass the complete URL in order to delete in the "YES" button in the modal. I am trying to simulate a process like this: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NePR0BQf3VmKtuMmhVR7?p=preview)

Here's the code.

Modal:

```
<div class="modal-body text-center">
      <p> Are you sure you want to remove this from the list? </p><br><br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom-1">Yes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Delete Button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-custom-3" data-href="<?php echo base_url() . 'admin_forms/delete_carsticker/' . $row->filename; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Delete </button>
```

Javascript:

```
  $('#delete-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.btn-custom-1').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a simple global variable to store the ID.

```
var delete_id = ""; // or a file name

$(document).on('click','.btn-custom-3', function(){
    delete_id = $(this).attr("data-href");
    // id also open the modal via jQuery too...  
});
```

then when you do the YES use the delete_id.

```
$(document).on('click','.btn-custom-1', function(){
    if(delete_id != ""){
        // do something with it and come the modal but you can close it like you are doing it directly in the HTML...
    }
});
```

Comment: How do I properly use the delete_id in YES? sorry I'm new to javascript

Comment: I updated my example.  Since the delete_id is global all the handlers can use it.

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter we have to use `base_url()`.It is MVC framework having models,views and controllers.

For delete there must be some function in controller to perform delete.

```
  <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class SomeClass extends CI_Controller {
   public function delete($id){
     $this->load->model('some_model');/* load model*/
      if($this->some_model->delete($id)){ /*$id is ID and delete is some function in some_model (Model)*/
        redirect('some_success_function')
       }else{
         redirect('previous_function')
       }
    }
 }
```

coming to html (views)

Urls will be as shown below

```
 <?php
if(isset($files)){
    foreach($files as $row){ 

        ?>
    <a href="#" data-href="<?php echo base_url() . 'admin_forms/delete_carsticker/' . $row->filename; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">Delete record #23</a><br>

    <button class="btn btn-default" data-href="<?php echo base_url() . 'admin_forms/delete_carsticker/' . $row->filename; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">
        Delete record #23
    </button>
<?php   }
}
?>
```

Here `SomeClass` is the controller `class` containing function `delete($id)` which take $id for deleting values. Controller call models function `delete($id)` to perform delete action.

**Edit**

I have updated the code, there is no problem in model part. I have run your code in localserver no problems in javascript. Check data are coming properly from controller , verify using `print_r($files)`

Comment: Hi! Yes, I currently have a controller and here's the code.
`function delete_carsticker($filename)
 {
  $this->session->set_flashdata('deletesuccess', 'You have successfully deleted the account.');
                $this->model_accounts->acc_delete($filename);
                redirect('admin_forms/car_sticker');
 }`

The main problem is that the modal YES button doesn't seem to get the URL taken by the controller, which is $filename in my case

Comment: check that proper file data are coming from controller to views